# How to use pygame to display something via HDMI on /dev/fb0 (using raspian OS lite)

Tags: pygame, framebuffer

I'm trying to get pygame to send *anything* to the framebuffer /dev/fb0 on a raspberry pi running the lite version of raspbian. I'm connected via ssh, the image should show up on the HDMI output.

I can send something to /dev/fb0 which shows up

```
sudo fbi -T 1 1.jpg
```

sends an image file, that I can see on the monitor

```
while true; do sudo cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0; sleep .01; done
```

sends white noise.

How do I connect pygame to "/dev/fb0"?

I tried many examples, but none work.

For example this code gives me a error

```
import os, pygame, time

def setSDLVariables(driver):
    print("Setting SDL variables...")
    os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb0"
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = driver
    print("...done") 

def printSDLVariables():
    print("Checking current env variables...")
    print("SDL_VIDEODRIVER = {0}".format(os.getenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER")))
    print("SDL_FBDEV = {0}".format(os.getenv("SDL_FBDEV")))

setSDLVariables('fbcon')
printSDLVariables()

try:
    pygame.init()
except pygame.error:
    print("Driver '{0}' failed!".format(driver))
size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
print("Detected screen size: {0}".format(size))
```

returns

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pve_img $ sudo python3 pg.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Setting SDL variables...
...done
Checking current env variables...
SDL_VIDEODRIVER = fbcon
SDL_FBDEV = /dev/fb0
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/pve_img/pg.py", line 22, in <module>
    size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Any hints on running pygame with a frame buffer in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

I had installed pygame using pip.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install pygame
```

Uninstalling pygame and the installing pygame differently

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
```

I can then send things to the screen. Example

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size )
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

for x in range(20):
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1)
    screen.fill((200, 200, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1)
```

installs a version that works with the above code.